# Adding Limits that do not exist

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I'm a bit confused about the idea of adding limits when they do not exist. I'm reading a book on Calculus, and it states that $ \lim_{x \to a} \ [f(x) + g(x)] $ exists in the following cases:

1. Both $ \lim_{x \to a} f(x) $ and $ \lim_{x \to a} \ g(x) $  exist.
2. Neither $ \lim_{x \to a} f(x) $ nor $ \lim_{x \to a} \ g(x) $ exists.

If that's the case, how can the following limit exist:

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \csc(x) \ + \lim_{x \to 0} \cot(x) \ = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1+\cos(x)}{\sin(x)} $$

Thanks!

Comment: Who says they exist?

Comment: No one said they exist, I just randomly came up with an example that, I think, contradicts that second argument - the limit of the sum of two functions exists if neither the limit of the first function nor the second exists. Am I misreading this somehow?

Comment: null, if you read your book a bit more carefully, you will find some context, some restrictions on $f,g,a$ that you have not yet told us

Comment: lim $f+g$ **may** exist if lim $f$ and lim $g$ don't, but there are plenty of examples where lim $f$ and lim $g$ don't exist and lim $f+g$ doesn't either

Comment: Yeah, I think that's what the author meant in the book. I read that statement as if that limit always exists under those conditions. Thank you guys for your comments!

Comment: It's possible what the book said (or meant to say) is that if the LHS limit (i.e., the limit of the sum) exists, then either *both* limits on the RHS exist or *neither* of them exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have misunderstood what the book says.

According to the algebraic limit theorem, $\lim_{x\to a}[f(x)+g(x)]=\lim_{x\to a}f(x)+ \lim_{x\to a}g(x),$

provided the limits on the right side exist.

It is possible for $\lim_{x\to a} [f(x)+g(x) ]$ to exist when $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ and $ \lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ do not,

but there are plenty of examples (such as the one you gave in the question)

where $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ and $ \lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ do not exist and $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)+g(x)$ does not either.

Perhaps the book was trying to say that you cannot have the situation where

$\lim_{x\to a} [f(x)+g(x) ]$ and $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$  exist but $ \lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ does not.